# How to resolve CORS error for AWS API Gateway implementing AWS Lambda function

Tags: html, node.js, aws-lambda, cors, aws-api-gateway

I have the following AWS lambda function below which is meant to call an API to list all country names from the API https://countriesnow.space/api/v0.1/countries/states. I have connected this AWS lambda to an API Gateway. I have been able to confirm with Postman that the API is working as required by verifying GET on "https://AWS-ID.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/locations?location=all".

```
import axios from 'axios';
    
    export const handler = async (event) => {
      try {
        console.log('EVENT');
        console.log(JSON.stringify(event, null, 2));
        
        if (event.rawPath === '/locations') {
          if (event.rawQueryString === 'location=all') {
            const countriesResponse = await axios.get('https://countriesnow.space/api/v0.1/countries/states');
      
            const countryNames = countriesResponse.data.data.map(country => country.name);
      
            return {
              statusCode: 200,
              headers: {
                "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" : "Content-Type",
                "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
                "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "OPTIONS,POST,GET"
              },
              body: JSON.stringify(countryNames),
            }; 
          } else {
            return {
              statusCode: 400,
              body: JSON.stringify({ message: 'Invalid endpoint' })
            };
          }
        } else {
          return {
            statusCode: 400,
            body: JSON.stringify({ message: 'Invalid endpoint' })
          };
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error:', error);
        return {
          statusCode: 500,
          body: JSON.stringify({ message: 'Internal Server Error' })
        };
      }
    };
```

The problem I'm currently facing is in regards to fetching the API in the HTML doc below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Country Dropdowns</title>
</head>
<body>

  <label for="country">Select Country:</label>
  <select id="country" onchange="fetchCountries()">
    <option value="">Select</option>
  </select>

  <br>

  <label for="state">Select State:</label>
  <select id="state">
    <option value="">Select</option>
  </select>

  <script>
    // Function to fetch countries from the API
    function fetchCountries() {
      fetch("https://AWS-ID.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/locations?location=all")
        .then(response => {
          if (!response.ok) {
            console.log(response)
            throw new Error(`HTTP error! Status: ${response.status}`);
          }
          return response.json();
        })
        .then(data => {
          console.log("Fetched countries:", data);
          const countryDropdown = document.getElementById("country");

          data.locations.forEach(country => {
            const option = document.createElement("option");
            option.value = country.code;
            option.textContent = country.name;
            countryDropdown.appendChild(option);
          });
        })
        .catch(error => console.error('Error fetching countries:', error));
    }

    // Fetch countries when the page loads
    fetchCountries();
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

The problem that I'm facing is related to CORS:

```
Access to fetch at 'https://AWS-ID.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/locations?location=all' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

These are the following CORS configs that I've put on the API

[image]

According to the resources I've read up on, the CORS configs look to be accurate but are there some configs that I'm missing preventing the API to be fetched? Any assistance on this would be much appreciated!

Comment: Did you deploy these changes by clicking on Deploy? It also takes some time. Around 5 minutes to reflect the changes.

Comment: All changes have been deployed.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why CORS from the console isn't working, but you can try to fix is from your API response.

In you lambda handler, pass the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin header`. Remove the CORS that you can set from the console by clicking on `Clear`.

```
return {
  statusCode: 200,
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*", // Required for CORS support to work
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    foo: "bar",
  }),
};
```